# How to clear all caches in Apache?

Tags: python, django, caching, cache-control, apache2.4

I have a django app running in a virtualenv on Windows 10 WSL1 (Ubuntu).  The python version is 3.6.8.

When using the django development web server, `python manage.py runserver`, everything is fine.  I access that with `http://localhost:8000/<my app name>/`

But when using apache2, version 2.4.29, **months-old javascript code shows up in the browser debugger** in a VMxxx file (though I haven't yet found an eval() that supposedly is the cause of the VMxxx being generated).

**Also, old server-side code shows up**:  an old javascript error that resulted from the django python code sending the wrong content type - a bug that was fixed a couple of weeks ago.

I'm accessing apache2 with `http://localhost/<my app name>/`

I disabled mod_cache:

```
a2dismod cache
Module cache already disabled.
```

Also ran `htcacheclean -r -l1k` and manually looked at the page cache directory, which was empty.

I clear the Chrome cache on every page load, but also get the same errors when using a different browser (Firefox) that wasn't even installed when this old code that's showing up was written.

I put in a HTTP header to request no caching:
`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />`

The closest thing to a cache that I have configured in Django settings is
`SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'`, 
no CACHES settings.

And, of course, I stopped and restarted Apache.

```
service apache2 stop
service apache2 start
```

All to no effect.

Where is this old code coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duh! I had copied (not moved) the entire directory tree to a different location, but didn't update the apache2 configuration, so it was still pointing to the old location.

I'm leaving this up in case someone else makes the same mistake.